# Attributes not appending with nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-forms

I'm trying to create a object from a nested form in rails, But I can't seem to get the params to look like they should.

I have a `Submission` and an `Attachment` models

#### ATTACHMENT

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader

  belongs_to :submission
end
```

#### SUBMISSION

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, inverse_of: :submission
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

#### CONTROLLER

```
def new
  @submission = ComplianceSubmission.new(user_id: current_user.id)
  @submission.attachments.build
end
```

FORM

```
<%= form.fields_for :attachments, submission.attachments do |attachment_fields| %>
  <%= attachment_fields.file_field :file %>
<% end %>
```

#### PARAMS

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tY5gRq1YJatO/wHHltCtBr34ZpgIAofJBCNcStiWUrAh0NavrAvHNjhesqMl0aRct9wlBQacpnaietb654JtsA==", "compliance_submission"=><ActionController::Parameters {"compliance_selection"=>"Professional Designation", "attachments"=>{"file", "compliance_conversation"=>"", "compliance_conversation_user"=>"Grady Ledner", "compliance_conversation_time"=>"Nov 10, 4:44 PM", "compliance_note"=>""} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Submit Form", "controller"=>"compliance_submissions", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

The nested attribute params go to the controller like this `"attachments"` and they should look like this `"attachments_attributes"`. Other wise the system doesn't know to create the model.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it a typo in your question or an actual bug in your code that your `Submission` model is called `Attachment`?

Comment: Oh, it's a typo

Comment: Try removing `submission.attachments` from your fields_for tag and use
`<%= form.fields_for :attachments do |attachment_fields| %>` directly and check for prams object if it works or not. 

Also, you need to add `attachment_attributes: [:file]` field to permitted params of Submission. As from your output, it shows that you have not permitted this field.